# Kullback-Leibler Divergence between 2 Histograms from an image (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I pulled histograms from images on matlab, than I want to compare the histograms using KL-divergence.
I found [this script](http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20688-kullback-leibler-divergence) but I do not understand how I could apply it to my case.

So here I pull my histogram (pretty simple!!):

```
[N,X]=hist(I,n);
[N1,X1]=hist(I1,n);
KLDiv(N,N1) 
% ans=inf
```

`N` is the histogram of my image `I`

Like you can see my result is `inf`...
 Please can you tell me in my case how to use the script?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to calculate the histogram of an image using [`imhist`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhist.html), instead of the columnwise calculation of the histogram:

```
I1 = rand(10);
I2 = rand(10);
[N1, X1] = imhist(I1, 10); % limit the number of bins to avoid zero values
[N2, X2] = imhist(I2, 10);

KLDiv(N1.', N2.') % convert to row vectors to correspond with the requested format
KLDiv(N1.', N1.') % the divergence of an histogram with itself is indeed zero
```

Note that I limited the number of bins to be sure that each bin has at least one point, because the [Kullback-Leibler divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) is not defined if Q(i) is zero and P(i) not:

> The Kullback–Leibler divergence is defined only if Q(i)=0 implies
>   P(i)=0, for all i (absolute continuity).

**Notes**

- *Range of Kullback–Leibler divergence?*
  Any positive number, zero if (and only if) they are equal: [KLD >= 0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties).
- *To which base should I take the logarithm? Natural logarithm `log` or base 2 logarithm `log2`?* 
  Note that it is just a matter of scaling your results. So in fact, it doesn't matter, but be sure to use the same logarithm if you want to compare your results. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition) suggests the following:

> logarithms in these formulae are taken to base 2 if information is
>   measured in units of [bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit), or to base e if information is measured in
>   [nats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nat_(unit)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I have 2 little questions, 
(1) I find my `KLD=1.2` is it possible? I thought that 0<=KLD<1 ..
(2) Should I use `log2` or `log` ? and why?

Comment: I just want to specify that in my case I will lose in precision if I use just 10 (number of bins), so I kept my 255 points and I added in the code: `temp(isinf(temp))=0;` `temp(isnan(temp))=0;` So in my result I no longer have `inf` or `NaN`